# Using CloudFlare API via PHP/Curl returning error

Tags: php, curl, cloudflare

I am working on updating my DNS via a PHP script. I've looked at the API documentation relating to cURL so I am trying to convert the cURL post to be PHP.

I have the following code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/<MY_ZONE>/dns_records/<MY_ID>");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

    $fields = array();
    $fields["X-Auth-Email"] = "someone@mydomain.com";
    $fields["X-Auth-Key"] = "MY_KEY";
    $fields["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $fields);

    $dnsData = array();
    $dnsData["id"] = "MY_ID";
    $dnsData["type"] = "A";
    $dnsData["name"] = "home";
    $dnsData["content"] = $newIPAddress;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($dnsData));


    echo "posting to API<br />";
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo "Result: " . $result;
```

With the above code I am getting the following response back from Cloudflare.

> {"success":false,"errors":[{"code":6003,"message":"Invalid request
>   headers","error_chain":[{"code":6100,"message":"Missing X-Auth-Email
>   header"},{"code":6101,"message":"Missing X-Auth-Key
>   header"},{"code":6105,"message":"Invalid Content-Type header, valid
>   values are
>   application/json,multipart/form-data"}]}],"messages":[],"result":null}

I've tried changing the json_encode to http_build_query instead but both return the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i think you are misusing curl_setopt.

This is the correct way to do set multiple header:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['HeaderName: HeaderValue','HeaderName2: HeaderValue2']);
```

**EDIT**

To make it more clear:

```
$headers = [ 
    'X-Auth-Email: someone@mydomain.com',
    'X-Auth-Key: MY_KEY',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Headers are not key/value pair, but rather only values.

Also, you should send POST data with http_build_query().

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're telling it to use `application/json` when you're passing it form data. Set your Content-type to `multipart/form-data` and it should work. If you want an example of how to use the JSON API, let me know.

> **EDIT:** CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER does not accept key/values, only values. [More information](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

`$fields["X-Auth-Email"] = "someone@mydomain.com";`
would therefore need to be changed to:
`$fields[]= "X-Auth-Email: someone@mydomain.com";`

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this code and i think you can use it without any problem.
example:

```
    $request_headers = array(
    'X-Auth-Email: user@emailaddress.com',
    'X-Auth-Key: d820fa8fc881921323e08a2c19b8347896ac26',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
```

then:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
```